# Laravel Vue хорошая ли практика

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, laravel, vue.js

Использую в своих разработках Laravel + vue и у меня возник один вопрос:
Хорошая ли эта практика передавать все возможные данные (например всю информацию о пользователе) c сервера (Laravel) посредством ajax (axios) в компоненты vue?

Есть же ещё вариант передачи из шаблона (blade) в компонент vue... Да, динамические данные "не передать", но информацию о пользователе который просто зашёл на сайт и отобразить её получится этим способом...
В общем, нуждаюсь в вашем совете, где что лучше и практичнее... (Или же всё получать ajax'ом и не париться :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В случае использования Vue + Laravel, по сути вы пишете 2 сайта, один - данные, другой - клиент для визуализации данных. В случае использования блэйда - у вас получается монолитное приложение.

Первый случай хорош, когда не нужно SEO и нужна скорость отрисовки страниц, а так же подразумевается использование ваших данных другими клиентами, будь это сторонние клиенты или приложения к вашему api.

Answer (score 1):

Хочу добавить: если использовать встроенный в laravel сетап vue то он не очень хорош, там через laravel mix компилируются стили и скрипты и они вставляются в blade, нет hot перезагрузки. Когда api на сервере и vue на клиенте, то это очень удобно и мощно, не знаю как вы там передаете данные, но полностью безапасные приложения можно делать. SEO и с vue будет такое же если использовать ssr, для этого есть классный фреймворк nuxt, есть 3 режима build сайта: spa, ssr(universal точнее) и даже генерировать много хтмл страниц с контентом что лучше по SEO чем spa, но не такое удобное. Если делать vue полностью отдельно, то еще есть проблема с stateless auth(jwt) авторизацией, есть только один популярный пакет и в нем плохая документация и много плохих примеров от людей. У меня есть пример сайта на nuxt: https://github.com/iliyaZelenko/laravel-nuxt. Я считаю что если использовать vue с laravel, то самый удобный и мощный вариант это использовать nuxt(для react есть next).